# LaTeX: vertical alignement in a table containing a listing

Tags: latex, listings, tabular

In LaTeX, I'm using the `listings` package to display some code snippet inside a table. But it seems that when using this package, the vertical alignement of the cells is changing.

Here is some code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline Méthode & Exemple d'utilisation\\
\hline isLetter()&
\begin{lstlisting}
QChar MyChar('x');
bool IsLetter = MyChar.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut vrai
// bla bla bla
\end{lstlisting}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and here is what I get (notice the centered vertical alignement of the first column) :

http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/8509/image4l.png.

If I avoid using the `listings` package inside the table, the vertical alignement is different (centered) :

```
\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
\hline Méthode & Exemple d'utilisation\\
\hline isLetter()&
QChar MyChar('x');
bool IsLetter = MyChar.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut vrai
// bla bla bla
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/8585/image5gy.png.

What I would like is to put some code inside the table *but* keep the vertical alignement to top for the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell latex to align it at the top of the baseline of its textline by the option `boxpos`.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[boxpos=t]
QChar MyChar('x');
bool IsLetter = MyChar.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut vrai
// bla bla bla
\end{lstlisting}
```

The problem also happens with other boxes

```
\parbox[t]{3cm}{Hello\\World\\Peace}
\parbox[t]{3cm}{Goodbye}
```

If you leave out the position parameter `t`, it will align both boxes centered relative to each other.

Comment: Thanks, it's working great (though it's still obscure why setting an option in the lstlisting bloc has an influence on the others) !